# How to fit children in parent dynamically with flex css

Tags: css, flexbox

I am using react to render images based on the entity's values dynamically. I never know beforehand whether the entity has 1 or 100 images, but i do know if it has `0 <`

I am trying to achieve something similar to the example below.
[image]

this question is marked as duplicate even though its clearly stating that i am asking for a solution utilizing flex values with dynamic content, not a set number of children with grid...

Comment: In fourth image, how did you decide the width of each image?, is that the minimum width of image? If size of images is not dependant on number of images, you can try flex-wrap

Comment: @SankethB.K already using flex wrap, im positive this should work with a good set of flex-basis, flex-grow and flex shrink values

Comment: Ok, i am guessing even after you use flex-wrap, you need to set flex-basis dynamically using JS depending on number of images you got, which requires some trial and error

Comment: Instead of flex-basis, i would calculate the width and height of images using JS, depending on number of images received. So that it fills the grid to the last row. This could be easier if the red container's dimensions are known beforehand

Comment: read the duplicate *carefully*. The trick explained there works with Grid and Flexbox. It's all about selectors that works with dynamic content. I added more duplicates using the same technique

Comment: @TemaniAfif I'm not sure if i am missing something here, but from what i am seeing i am required to create N classes for N options. so if an entity has 1000 pictures i have to create 1000 cases and/or classes

Comment: I don't know where you see me creating classes in the duplicates. In one of the duplicate I wrote only 5 selector to cover up to 20 images. I didn't write 20 classes for 20 images. everything is dynamically handled, nothing is statically defined. Take the time to check the duplicates

Comment: @TemaniAfif Actually the second reference is quite good, however i am experiencing an overflow.